# Получить доступ к изображению, которое находится в assets

Tags: android, файлы, изображения

Пишу

```
File file = new File("assets:///img/mirror01.jpg");
```

Получаю

> ```
> assets:/img/mirror01.jpg (No such file or directory)
> ```

Как исправить?

Comment: Разве с ассетами не через `AssetManager` нужно работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
public void loadImageFromAsset() {
try {
    InputStream ims = mContext.getAssets().open("img/mirror01.jpg");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);      
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Напишите этот код:

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("default_book.txt");
```